# Template class assignment operator

Tags: c++, class, templates, assignment-operator

I have a problem with a template class I named "DynamicArray". The only problem that I have is when I define my assignment operator. it gives me two different errors

1) the first error it gives me is

DynamicArray& says "argument list for class template "DynamicArray" is missging"

2) the second error is

DynamicArray::operator= says "template argument list must match the parameter list"

this is my program:

**DynamicArray.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class DynamicArray
{
public:
    DynamicArray();
    DynamicArray(const DynamicArray &d);
    DynamicArray& operator=(const DynamicArray &d);
    ~DynamicArray();
};

template<typename T>
DynamicArray<T>::DynamicArray()
{

}

template<typename T>
DynamicArray<T>::DynamicArray(const DynamicArray &d)
{

}

template<typename T>
DynamicArray& DynamicArray<T>::operator=(const DynamicArray &d)
{

}

template<typename T>
DynamicArray<T>::~DynamicArray()
{

}
```

I have looked at multiple examples and can't figure out why I have this problem.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Apart from anything else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: ... and `operator=` should return a `DynamicArray<T>&`.

Comment: "argument list for class template "DynamicArray" is missing" is quite verbose. You want to return `DynamicArray` by reference, but you didn't specify it's template argument, so compiler doesn't know what exactly do you want to return (in case you wanted to always return `DynamicArray<int>` for some reason...)

Comment: I tried having the definitions in the same header file before moving them to the .cpp file and had the same problem.

Comment: Only one of them. Fixing the one I mentioned would have removed the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the complete template in the header file as Neil suggested via the link to [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).
2. The return value from `operator=` should be `DynamicArray<T>&`